# MySQL Trigger Update with select from another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

Just learning about triggers and I'm created the following trigger;

```
CREATE TRIGGER `incremental_before_ins_tr` BEFORE INSERT ON incremental`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.source = (Select source from crm_record
where msisdn = new.msisdn order by dat DESC limit 1);
END;
```

However the value does not appear to be getting updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

I've actually managed to solve this myself. Here is the updated code

```
CREATE TRIGGER `incremental_before_ins_tr` BEFORE INSERT ON `incremental`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.source = (Select source from crm_record
where crm_record.msisdn = new.msisdn order by dat DESC limit 1);
END;
```

I needed to specify the table name prior to the column value on line 5.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo.

You have entered incremental with a trailing backtick instead of enclosing it in backticks.

It is likely that your trigger is now bound to a table called `` incremental` `` which I am assuming does not exist.

Since you have ruled out the above.  I see that the UPDATE keyword is missing.  Add `UPDATE table` before your SET line. Replace table with the name of your table.

Comment: That's actually a typo in this entry, it was bound to the correct table

Comment: Tried that and got the following error **Can't update table incremental in stored function /trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this function/trigger**